# SQL (How do I display all results from all tables?)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I would love if someone could help me with this.

I have 3 tables

Table1
Table2
Talbe3

(They are almost the same, but however some columns are slightly different)

What I wanted to ask you is how do I display all results from all 3 tables (including rows and columns) on a webpage.

Also how do I make the search bar look through all 3 tables.

For example, if I someone searches by First name or Last Name ("An")
So the results display rows from all 3 tables that contain "An" for example (Annete, Andrew, Anamari, Andrea) etc.

Thank you

Comment: If the tables are not the same, then issue three different queries.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: Did you code anything yet, Doe?

Comment: have you tried anything ? if so please update your question with that

Answer (score 0):

**Try UNION:**
If your three tables have the same number of columns, then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 WHERE FirstName LIKE 'An%' OR LastName LIKE 'An%' UNION SELECT Table2.* FROM Table2 WHERE FirstName LIKE 'An%' OR LastName LIKE 'An%' UNION SELECT Table3.* FROM Table3 WHERE FirstName LIKE 'An%' OR LastName LIKE 'An%'
```

If Not, you can specify the fields you need:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Table1 WHERE FirstName LIKE 'An%' OR LastName LIKE 'An%' UNION SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Table2 WHERE FirstName LIKE 'An%' OR LastName LIKE 'An%' UNION SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Table3 WHERE FirstName LIKE 'An%' OR LastName LIKE 'An%'
```